# Rails ERB <%- ... -%> vs. <% ... %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between -%> and %> in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails)

So for an ERB file, what's the difference between <%- ... -%> vs. <% ... %>? As far as I can tell, they serve the same purpose but one requires more typing than the other.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using the dash removes the whitespace around the ERB tag, there is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/100-5-view-tips) that talks about this and some other View tricks.

Comment: As of rails v4.2.1, <% %> and <%- -%> are the same. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Base