# Whats the difference between "%>" and "-%>"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between -%> and %> in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails)

What's the difference between `%>` and `-%>` ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash removes whitespace around your ERB tag

also answered here
[Rails ERB <%- ... -%> vs. <% ... %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529927/rails-erb-vs)

Answer (score 1):

in rails 3 - no difference 
in earlier versions, whether or not a carriage return was added