# where do devise_mapping.registerable?, devise_mapping.recoverable?....come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

where do `devise_mapping.registerable?`, `devise_mapping.recoverable?`....come from? I mean I can't find a file where they are indicated, can find nothing about them.

And why is there always a "-" in the if..end structures? For instance:

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Rails server is started, inside the `devise` gem code [lib/devise/modules.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/modules.rb) calls `add_module` for all the available modules.  [lib/devise.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb) calls `Devise::Mapping.add_module module_name`.  [lib/devise/mapping.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mapping.rb) then builds the methods like `registerable?` using this code:

```
# Create magic predicates for verifying what module is activated by this map.
# Example:
#
#   def confirmable?
#     self.modules.include?(:confirmable)
#   end
#
def self.add_module(m)
  class_eval <<-METHOD, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{m}?
      self.modules.include?(:#{m})
    end
  METHOD
end
```

If you run the Rails console and then look at one of your devise resources such as `:user`, you can see the methods that were built by checking out `Devise.mappings[:user].methods.sort` and you can see the modules that you decided to include in your user model with `Devise.mappings[:user].modules`.

The "-" in the `<% %>` code has to do with omitting white space, though it may not be necessary anymore or might vary by browser because there isn't always a noticeable difference (See: [Rails ERB <%- ... -%> vs. <% ... %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529927/rails-erb-vs) and [Difference between -%> and %> in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails)).