# what does dash mean in ruby on rails html scriptlet?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scriptlet

In the web I've seen examples both with

```
<% if @showIt -%>
  some html content
<% end -%>
```

and without

```
<% if @showIt %>
  some html content
<% end %>
```

dash. Both versions work very well. So, what difference does it make?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used to avoid inserting a newline after the code.

I found a very nice explanation [here](http://www.plexusweb.com/staff/travis/blog/post/117/Rails-inline-ERb-effects-on-HTML-structure).

Comment: Thanks, somehow googling didn't help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The above link seems broken, it is beautifully explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails) stack post