# What does -%> mean in Ruby on Rails, compared to %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've always used `<%= some_code %>` to insert Ruby into HTML when using Ruby on Rails. I've just noticed that other projects sometimes use `<%= some_code -%>`.

Comment: Superset question for all formats `<% %>` modifiers that came later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax

Comment: @CiroSantilli: You're dominating these - nice work! I picked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails for this one, too...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<%= some_code -%> The minus at the end removes the newline. Useful for formatting the generated HTML, while <%= some_code %> does not.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: What about the difference between starting with `<%=` vs `<%`?

Comment: @ShawnSep `=` addes the output, `%` does not and is used for stuff like conditionals `<% if %>`.

Answer (score 4):

It's delete on Rails 3.

Now with Rails 3, there are no difference between this 2 forms.

Comment: Not sure where you read that, but -%> still stops ERB from producing a trailing newline in rails 3.

Comment: According to the Rails 3 release notes: "You no longer need to place a minus sign at the end of a ruby interpolation inside an ERb template to remove the trailing carriage return in the HTML output."

Comment: @Tim That means it will remove the trailing CR from your HTML output, not from every line. -%> still exists and is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was wrong: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617607/895245 instead.

---

In Ruby 2.1 (not necessarily with Rails), the `-` removes one following newline as pointed by Anubhaw:

- the newline must be the first char after the `>`
- no spaces are removed
- only a single newline is removed
- you *must* pass the `'-'` option to use it

Examples:

```rb
require 'erb'
ERB.new("<%= 'a' %>\nb").result              == "a\nb"  or raise
begin ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\nb").result; rescue SyntaxError ; else raise; end
ERB.new("<%= 'a'  %>\nb"  , nil, '-').result == "a\nb"  or raise
ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\nb"  , nil, '-').result == 'ab'    or raise
ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%> \nb" , nil, '-').result == "a \nb" or raise
ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\n b" , nil, '-').result == 'a b'   or raise
ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\n\nb", nil, '-').result == "a\nb"  or raise
```

Doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Rails 4.1 appears to:

- use ERB by default at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fcbdac7e82725c388bf5adf56a9a9a16d4efdbe0/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb#L10
- set `-` by default at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fcbdac7e82725c388bf5adf56a9a9a16d4efdbe0/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L77