# erb how to loop on array

Tags: ruby, loops, parsing, erb

I can't simply loop on an array with ruby erb template system...

here is my template:

```
<% ['foo', 'bar'].each do |val| -%>
<%= val %>
<% end -%>
```

Here is the command line and the result

```
erb test.erb
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:896:in `eval': test.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ';' (SyntaxError)
'foo', 'bar'].each do |val| -; _erbout.concat "\n"
                              ^
test.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ';'
;  end -; _erbout.concat "\n"
         ^
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:896:in `result'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:878:in `run'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/erb:149:in `run'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/erb:170:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong with this really simple example?

Disclaimer: I am a ruby and erb noob ^^

Comment: The thing that error message is also pretty unclear. To me, it should have told you unexpected '-'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to have those "-" at the end before the "%".

```
<% ['foo', 'bar'].each do |val| %>
    <%= val %>
<% end %>
```

This should work.

Comment: indeed it works! but I don't understand, the "-"is here to not add a newline char (from my understanding).

I saw a lot of examples with this syntax.

Why am i not supposed to use the "-" here ?

Comment: @nemenems Seems like you need to enable it doing `ERB.new(template, nil, '-')`, see this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632879/erb-template-removing-the-trailing-line

Comment: perfect! you rocks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to set *trim mode* to `-`:

```
$ erb -T - test.erb
foo
bar
```

From the man page:

> ```
> -T mode   Specifies trim mode (default 0). mode can be one of
>           0   EOL remains after the embedded ruby script is evaluated.
>           1   EOL is removed if the line ends with %>.
>           2   EOL is removed if the line starts with <% and ends with %>.
>           -   EOL is removed if the line ends with -%>. And leading whitespaces
>               are removed if the erb directive starts with <%-.
> ```