# What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, erb

Can some one please describe the usage of the following characters which is used in ERB file:

```
<%   %>
<%=  %>
<%  -%>
<%#  %>
```

what's the usage of each one ?

Comment: You've got some great answers here. Also note that Haml is often a superior alternative to ERb.

Comment: Yes, it is much easier to deal with than ERb

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between -%> and %> in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998979/difference-between-and-in-rails) for `-%>`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952403/without-equal-in-ruby-erb-means for `<%=`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901619/how-to-comment-lines-in-rails-html-erb-files for `<%#`.

Comment: @Ciro Santilli: Despite the age, this one seems more complete than your references. I'm voting to close those as dupes of this one..

Comment: `<%= %>` and `<%= -%>` are different: only the latter removes trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 535, accepted):

```
<% %>
```

Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

```
<%= %>
```

Prints something into erb file.

```
<%== %>
```

Equivalent to `<%= raw %>`. Prints something verbatim (i.e. w/o escaping) into erb file. (Taken from [Ruby on Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety).)

```
<% -%>
```

Avoids line break after expression.

```
<%# %>
```

Comments out code within brackets; not sent to client (as opposed to HTML comments).

Visit [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for more infos about ERB.

Comment: i have met somewhere in code this variant else <%== %>
does anyone know what is it?

Comment: The double equal means that the string is not escaped, as in raw.

Comment: Rails does not use the stdlib ERB: it uses erubis: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16766#issuecomment-54148778

Comment: But... but... `<%#` is just a normal `<%` with a Ruby comment `#` right after it.... Yeah, it's fun to think it's something special, but isn't it just an ERB idiom rather than a special syntactic construct?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria I'm fairly certain it's treated specially -- as in, instead of the comment being read and processed, like it would be if it was just a Ruby comment, it's skipped entirely. The effect is the same, though.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes sorry about that, you're right... For example, if you have multiline ERB `<%...%>`, `<%#...%>` comments out _all_ of it, which it wouldn't do if it was just a normal comment (i.e. it would only comment out the line it's on).

Comment: DONT FORGET '<%%'   If anyone has used Chart.js in an erb template they've needed to do this for tooltips lol the <%% basically means dont interpret the '<%' .

Comment: Nowadays, Rails uses Erubi, a simplified fork of Erubis. https://rubygems.org/gems/erubi

Answer (score 94):

`<% %>` and `<%- and -%>` are for any Ruby code, but doesn't output the results (e.g. if statements). the two are the same.

`<%= %>` is for outputting the results of Ruby code

`<%# %>` is an ERB comment

Here's a good guide:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Comment: I don't see that opening `<%-` does anything for leading whitespace, and I don't see it documented anywhere. Are you sure about that? Maybe it's a different flavour of ERB. There's no option shown for it on the stdlib docs.

Comment: @AndrewVit - From the page referenced in this answer (ActionView::Base docs page):

"<%- and -%> suppress leading and trailing whitespace, including the trailing newline, and can be used interchangeably with <% and %>."

Comment: How to suppress leading whitespace for <%= %> ?

Answer (score 70):

Rails does **not** use the [stdlib's ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) by default, it uses [erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/). Sources: [this dev's comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16766#issuecomment-54148778), [ActionView's gemspec](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/actionview.gemspec#L25), [accepted merge request I did while writing this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16774).

There *are* behavior differences between them, in particular on how the hyphen operators `%-` and `-%` work.

Documentation is scarce, [Where is Ruby's ERB format "officially" defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910212/where-is-rubys-erb-format-officially-defined) so what follows are empirical conclusions.

All tests suppose:

```
require 'erb'
require 'erubis'
```

**When you can use `-`**

- ERB: you must pass `-` to `trim_mode` option of `ERB.new` to use it.
- erubis: enabled by default.

Examples:

```
begin ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\nb").result; rescue SyntaxError ; else raise; end
ERB.new("<%= 'a' -%>\nb"  , nil, '-') .result == 'ab'  or raise
Erubis::Eruby.new("<%= 'a' -%>  \n b").result == 'a b' or raise
```

**What `-%` does:**

- ERB: remove the next character if it is a newline.
- erubis:

  - in `<% %>` (without `=`), `-` is useless because `<% %>` and `<% -%>` are the same. `<% %>` removes the current line if it only contains whitespaces, and does nothing otherwise.
  - in `<%= -%>` (with `=`):

    - remove the entire line if it only contains whitespaces
    - else, if there is a non-space before the tag, and only whitesapces after, remove the whitespces that come after
    - else, there is a non-space after the tag: do nothing

Examples:

```
# Remove
ERB.new("a \nb <% 0 -%>\n c", nil, '-').result == "a \nb  c" or raise

# Don't do anything: not followed by newline, but by space:
ERB.new("a\n<% 0 -%> \nc", nil, '-').result == "a\nb \nc" or raise

# Remove the current line because only whitesapaces:
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <% 0 %> \nb").result == 'b' or raise

# Same as above, thus useless because longer.
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <% 0 -%> \nb").result == 'b' or raise

# Don't do anything because line not empty.
Erubis::Eruby.new("a <% 0 %> \nb").result == "a  \nb" or raise
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <% 0 %> a\nb").result == "  a\nb" or raise
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <% 0 -%> a\nb").result == "  a\nb" or raise

# Don't remove the current line because of `=`:
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <%= 0 %> \nb").result == " 0 \nb" or raise

# Remove the current line even with `=`:
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <%= 0 -%> \nb").result == " 0b"   or raise

# Remove forward only because of `-` and non space before:
Erubis::Eruby.new("a <%= 0 -%> \nb").result == "a 0b"   or raise

# Don't do anything because non-whitespace forward:
Erubis::Eruby.new(" <%= 0 -%> a\nb").result == " 0 a\nb"   or raise
```

**What `%-` does:**

- ERB: remove whitespaces before tag and after previous newlines, but only if there are only whitespaces before.
- erubis: useless because `<%- %>` is the same as `<% %>` (without `=`), and this cannot be used with `=` which is the only case where `-%` can be useful. So never use this.

Examples:

```
# Remove
ERB.new("a \n  <%- 0 %> b\n c", nil, '-').result == "a \n b\n c" or raise

# b is not whitespace: do nothing:
ERB.new("a \nb  <%- 0 %> c\n d", nil, '-').result == "a \nb   c\n d" or raise
```

**What `%-` and `-%` do together**

The exact combination of both effects separately.

Comment: On the second line you have written that Rails uses eruby while linking to erubis.

Comment: @DanielJonsson thanks for the report: it was meant to be erubis. Going nuts with so many versions. Updated.

Answer (score 11):

- `<% %>` : Executes the ruby code
- `<%= %>` : Prints into Erb file. Or browser
- `<% -%>` : Avoids line break after expression.
- `<%# %>` : ERB comment

Answer (score 8):

I've added the `<%%` literal tag delimiter as an answer to this because of its obscurity.  This will tell erb not to interpret the `<%` part of the tag which is necessary for js apps like displaying chart.js tooltips etc.

**Update (Fixed broken link)**

Everything about ERB can now be found here:
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_template_erb.html#tags

Comment: this link answers the OP accurately

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: Updated with the new link!

Answer (score 3):

**These are use in ruby on rails**   :-

**<%   %> :-**

The <% %> tags are used to execute Ruby code that does not return anything, such as conditions, loops or blocks. Eg :-

```
<h1>Names of all the people</h1>
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  Name: <%= person.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

**<%= %> :-**

use to display the content .

```
Name: <%= person.name %><br>
```

**<%  -%>:-**

Rails extends ERB, so that you can suppress the newline simply by adding a trailing hyphen to tags in Rails templates

**<%# %>:-**

comment out the code

```
<%# WRONG %>
Hi, Mr. <% puts "Frodo" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%   %>` executes the code in there but does not print the result, for eg:
We can use it for if else in an erb file.

```
<% temp = 1 %>
<% if temp == 1%>
  temp is 1
<% else %>
  temp is not 1
<%end%>
```

Will print `temp is 1`

---

`<%=  %>` executes the code and also prints the output, for eg:
We can print the value of a rails variable.

```
<% temp = 1 %>
<%= temp %>
```

Will print `1`

---

`<%  -%>` It makes no difference as it does not print anything, `-%>` only makes sense with `<%= -%>`, this will avoid a new line.

---

`<%#  %>` will comment out the code written within this.