# Embedded ruby "erb" tags

Tags: ruby, tags, erb

I have been going through a crash course of Ruby and Ruby on Rails and i can't figure this out:
In embedded ruby html files, there are several tags.
<% %> for execution
<%= %> for output, but what function do these tags serve: <%= -%>, what's with the "-" sign at the end ?

Thanks.

Comment: The difference is explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7996695/158689)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100215150502/http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/erb/) contains a good overview of erb markup.

From the site:

> > RECOGNIZED TAGS
>
> ERB recognizes certain tags in the provided template and converts
>   them based on the rules below:
>
> ```
> <% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
>
> <%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
>
> <%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
>
> % a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
>
> %% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
>
> <%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
> ```
>
> All other text is passed through ERB filtering unchanged.

Comment: Links is dead. An archived version: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100215150502/http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/erb/

Answer (score 1):

In ruby document there is not the details about this usage `<%-` or `-%>`. But it works well by this:

`erbA = ERB.new(erbA_str, 1, '-', "@output_buffer")`

Notice the 3rd parameter `'-'`
! 
It removes the pre or post blanks when using `<%-` and `-%>` accordingly.