# What is the <%= %> tag in this HTML called?

Tags: html

I found this `<%= %>` tag in some HTML, I haven't seen this in any tutorials. What is this called?

```
<div class="lt-toggle-btn" >
        <div class = "row">
            <a class="reflection-questions-title" href="#resources/videos/<%- CONTENTID %>">
                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                <p class="reflection-title col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11"><%- CONTENTNAME %></p>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was it in core related to Ruby on Rails that you saw this pattern?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208728/embedded-ruby-erb-tags

Comment: Heres a link to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal

Comment: Could also be ASP shorthand for response.write.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski- It could also be a JSP tag to embed return value of an expression. Where did you encounter this OP ?

Comment: It's not HTML. You are not giving us all the information. -1

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, these are called Code Render Blocks.
You can check these links for details:

[Code Render Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.71).aspx) and [Embedded Code Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: thanks. thanks now I can proceed. Too bad I can't upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `erb` or `Embedded RuBy` tag. It is widely used in the Ruby on Rails website development platform. More can be found [here](http://rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0):

That is in ASP, opening and closing tags. It is a different language completely form html

<% is the open and %> closes. with the hyphens, its a comment.

Comment: Why would a comment be used here? That makes no sense and suggests that this is something else instead.