# SyntaxError in Posts#new - an unexpected journey

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why im feeling that someone is under my `mousepoint_jumps`?
that is the error:
`SyntaxError in Posts#new` when i load the page and:

```
C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...ppend= ( if @post.errors.any? );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
...                               ^
C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
');  end 
        ^
C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'); end ;@output_buffer.to_s
       ^
C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1: <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
2:  <%= if @post.errors.any? %>
3:  <div id="errorExplanation">
4:      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
5:          this post from beign saved:</h2>
```

and this is the file:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
            this post from beign saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <%= @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

im working in that ruby tutorial hard and deeply, but something is behind
the nice errors. I love the errors, is true. But this is too much!
Can i get any evidence of my wrong work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the follwing (notice `<%=` has been replace by `<%`)

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
```

Same thing for

```
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

See [this question on ERB syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax) for more details. Basically `<%=` is used to insert dynamic content in the page; `<%` is for control statements (conditions, loops, etc...).

Comment: thanks. looks like the errors are less now.