# Escape String - Output rails string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to assign a string value to a javascript object in my .erb file like so:

```
var data = {
    'name': '<%= @product.name %>',
    ...
};
```

The problem is, if the value of `name` is `Tom's small ears`,

the output of `data.name` would be `Tom&#x27;s small ears`.

Is there a way to escape special characters?

I tried doing `'name': '<%= raw @product.name %>'` but `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` gets output into the console.

Doing `<%= escape_javascript @product.name %>` outputs `Tom\&#x27;s small ears`

**Edit**
@Stefan's comment under `MrYoshiji's` answer worked for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `escape_javascript()` to accomplish that:

```
var data = {
    'name': "<%== escape_javascript @product.name %>",
    #...
};
```

Link:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

The alias of this method is `j`:

```
 var data = {
     'name': "<%== j @product.name %>"
 }
```

Comment: The output is now `Tom\&#x27;s small ears`

Comment: It does display `Tom\'s small ears` for me in my views when I test this code. Try to directly print `<%= j @product.name %>` in a view (not in a javascript tag) and see if the output is the one desired.

Comment: It works when I output it directly, but I want to put the value in a javascript variable

Comment: I think the Javascript understands that this `&#x27;` is actually a '. Try to alert or console.log this value to see if Javascript replaces this ASCII code into the corresponding caracter '.

Comment: Rails seems to escape `'`, try `<%==` instead of `<%=`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, can you please explain to me (or point to documentation) what's the difference beween <%== and <%= ? Google is not good at looking for special symbols (or I'm not good at googling them)

Comment: @Ievgen see the first answer's second comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails quoting: *"The double equal means that the string is not escaped, as in raw"*

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = {
   'name': '<%=j @product.name.html_safe %>',
   ...
};
```

Comment: Please do not do this unless you have already verified that `@product.name` is a sanitized string that will not cause an HTML injection.

Comment: @Andrew I believe the `j` (short for `escape_javascript`) will correctly escape the string regardless, right? (meaning that the example here is fine, except that the call to `html_safe` should be unnecessary).