# How to handle string that has both " and '?

Tags: ruby, erb

I need to render this string that is stored in db:

```
<span style=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; line-height: 40px;\">Potentiometer</span>
```

When I try to assign it to a var like this:

```
var description:"<%= s.html_safe %>";
```

I get this error near `'Open Sans'` :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Although I used `'` not `"` at `var description:"<%= s.html_safe %>";` the resulted javascript will look like:

```
var description= '<span style=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; line-height: 40px;\">Potentiometer</span>';
```

This will cause an error as string starts with `'` and it has `'` too

Can someone help?

EDIT

The solution found is to use gsub and replace each `'` with `"`

```
<%- s= raw(s.gsub(/'/, "\"")) %>

$scope.circuits.unshift({circuit:"<%= @experiment.circuit %>", description:'<%=s%>'});
```

Comment: What language are you using?  Ruby does not use `var` to declare variables.

Comment: why not escape the quotes, i.e. \'Open Sans\' (since it's from db, with js replace for example)

Comment: its javascript with ruby, I 've found the solution anyway, thanks guys, see the edit

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854749

Comment: Please don't use `raw` with `gsub`. Follow the link @ArieShaw posted and use `escape_javascript`.