# ruby on rails: weird array output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in on of my views

```
<%= @quotes.each do |f| %>
   <%=f[:underwriter]%>: £<%=f[:premium]%>
   <br>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller I pass it the argument

```
 @quotes = [{underwriter:"dtc",premium:500},{underwriter:"abc",premium:800}]
```

I expect it to print out the underwriter and premium, which it does, however it tags the whole array on at the end for some reason. This is shown below

```
dtc: £500 
abc: £800 
[{:underwriter=>"dtc", :premium=>500}, {:underwriter=>"abc", :premium=>800}]
```

Anyone can enlighten my to what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: remove the `=` from the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
<% @quotes.each do |f| %>
   <%=f[:underwriter]%>: £<%=f[:premium]%>
   <br>
<% end %>
```

[Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) - Calls the given block once for each element in self, passing that element as a parameter. when iteartion completed, return the `self`. `<%= %>` prints what is in between inside the tag into erb file, whereas `<% %>` executes the ruby code within the brackets.

Check this one [*Rails, ERB syntax*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax) also.

Comment: cheers for the clarification. Pesky = sign