# High Voltage Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I'm having a problem setting up High Voltage gem for my static pages.

I have a view/pages folder with 'privacy' and 'terms' files in it.

In my _footer.html.erb, I have:

```
<% link_to "Privacy", page_path('privacy')%>
```

I have nothing in my routes file.

When I run the server, the footer file doesn't display a link to Privacy (at all) and when I drag the mouse across the field, all I can highlight is the copyright notice which appears in the line above this link.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see: [Rails, ERB syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax)

Comment: You're missing the '=' in your erb code:  <%= link_to "Privacy", page_path('privacy') %> ...  If you want your erb to output something to the page you need that equals in there.

Answer (score 0):

You missed "=" sign into your link_to call. So it should be

"<%**=** link_to "Privacy", page_path('privacy')%>"