# Correct Indentation for the closing </a> tag in ERB / Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Is there a way to fix the `</a>` tag's indentation in `link_to` helpers?

**in my .html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to... do %>
...
<% end %>
```

**in rendered .html:**

```
     <a href="..">
</a><!--fails to inherit the indentation-->
```

**2-space indentation in IDE:**

[image]

**Chrome's `view-source:*`:**

[image]

Comment: I'd upvote you 5 times for noticing this and taking the time to ask. And I'll hate you when I can't avoid noticing that myself :-)

Comment: On my app, the `</a>` tag does indent properly. Am guessing it must be something you are adding in between  (i.e. as part of `perfectionist hell to follow`) that is messing up the indentation.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy. Nope. `perfectionist hell to follow` is just plain text I used as an example. Try it yourself and change the text to anything you want. Normally, I would use the space for icon font tags for buttons and links.

Answer (score 0):

That is still valid HTML, so you could ignore it.

It depends on how ERB (powered by [erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) in Rails) handles leading and trailing whitespace in the string buffer that will be inserted in the rendered text.

You can try with `<%=  -%>`. Also [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) for the difference.