# Suppressing spaces in ERB template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Why does this produce the desired output (a list of team names, separated by commas):

```
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%><%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>
    <%= link_to t.name, team_path(t) -%>
<%- end %>
```

Output: One, Two, Three

And this not:

```
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%>
    <%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>
    <%= link_to t.name, team_path(t) -%>
<%- end %>
```

Output: One , Two , Three

My understanding is that the "-%>" should suppress the space before the comma. But clearly my understanding (or Rails 4.2.0) is wrong.

Comment: `-%>` behaves differently if using 'erb' vs 'erubis' libraries (ruby vs rails). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if [*trim_mode*](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) is `-`, then `ERB` omit blank lines ending in `-%>`.

Look at the first code and its output :

```
require 'erb'

erb = ERB.new <<_, 0, '-'
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%>
<%= ',' unless i == 0  %> # here I have removed `-`
<%= t -%>
<%- end %>
_

teams = %w( India USA Brazil )
puts erb.result binding
# >> 
# >> India,
# >> USA,
# >> Brazil
```

Now the look at the effect of the `-` in `-%>` from the below code :

```
require 'erb'

erb = ERB.new <<_, 0, '-'
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%>
<%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>
<%= t -%>
<%- end %>
_

teams = %w( India USA Brazil )
puts erb.result binding
# >> India,USA,Brazil
```

And,

```
require 'erb'

erb = ERB.new <<_, 0, '-'
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%> <%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>
<%= t -%>
<%- end %>
_

teams = %w( India USA Brazil ) 
puts erb.result binding
# >>  India ,USA ,Brazil
```

I don't think there is anything from `ERB` side to strip out the *white spaces*. One way to get rid of this is adjusting the *ERB template* itself.

```
require 'erb'

erb = ERB.new <<_, 0, '-'
<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%><%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>
<%= t -%>
<%- end %>
_

teams = %w( India USA Brazil )
puts erb.result binding
# >> India,USA,Brazil
```

Railish way is :

```
<%= teams.map { |t| link_to t.name, team_path(t) }.join(', ').html_safe %>
```

Here is some *reasoning* about the first code :

`<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%>` will be deleted as you added `-` for each iteration. Now the next is `<%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>`, which will not be there for the fist time, but next iterations onward. But every time `,` will come without trailing *space*, as its previous *erb* tag getting deleted by `-`.

Here is some *reasoning* about the second code :

`<% teams.each_with_index do |t,i| -%>` will be deleted as you added `-` for each iteration. Now the next line is `<%= ',' unless i == 0  -%>`, which will not be there for the fist time, but next iterations onward. Now this has some extra indentation *space*, which is causing a **space** before every **,**. **[single space],**

Comment: And the reason that the newlines don't come through in the second example is because HTML ignores newlines in text.

Comment: @Beartech I agree with you

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks for adding the rails way which was what I really needed. It's a pity ERB doesn't have a mechanism to suppress leading white space before a <%=.