# unable to retrieve data from a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to access the data from a form.

```
<% form_tag(:action => "test") do %>
<p>
    Name:
    <%= text_field_tag("name","web programmer") %>
</p>
<%= submit_tag ("Save data") %>
<% end %>
```

this form is in views/challenges/show.html
I have written this piece of code in challenges_controller

```
def test
    @name = params[:name]

    end
before_filter :test
```

now,If i try to access @name variable in views/challenges/show.html
heres the code for that part

```
<% if @name != null %>
<%= @name  %>
<% end  %>
```

I get the following error
"undefined local variable or method `null' "

i have addded the following route to my routes.rb

```
get 'challenges/test'
```

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: `null` should be `nil`..

Comment: thanks I tried it but i get the following error
"No route matches [POST] "/challenges/test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display your form so instead of using <% %> you need to use <%= %>, checkout [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) for differences between them. *By default forms use POST verb and **you have defined a route for GET request.** Change your form to this:*

```
<%= form_tag({action: :test}, {method: :get}) do %>
  <p>
    Name:
    <%= text_field_tag("name","web programmer") %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag ("Save data") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks I changes the form and replaced "null" with 'nil'
but now i get the following error
"No route matches [POST] "/challenges/test""

Comment: Thanks i tried the updated form 
and i  still get the same error
"No route matches [POST] "/challenges/test"
The url just changed to "http://localhost:3000/challenges/test?method=get"
I am able to display the form by the way

Comment: sorry but the same issue continues 
I just keep on getting the same error
"No route matches [POST] "/challenges/test",
though i have changed the method to "get" @mandeep

Comment: @pokiri try updated answer. I have tested it locally so it will work :)

Comment: thanks 
i get some error as"Missing template challenges/test, application/test"
the error is highlighted at this line::
"find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))"

I am using activeAdmin,kaminari gems in my application
does this create any issue???
sorry for troubling you @mandeep

Comment: @pokiri you don't have template for test action. Either rename views/challenges/show.html.erb to views/challenges/test.html.erb or create a new one or inside test action you can render template of show action by render 'show'

Comment: Thanks a lot 
it worked i just changed my 'action' attribute in form to 'show' 
and placed 
@name = params[:name] in my 'show' method