# Why is this passing of params into link_to not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

Still can't get this working after trying several things noted in the initial comments - I've revised below to reflect those efforts / clarify a few things.

Problem summary: I cannot create a new Post (an answer) where the parent_id of that Post equals the id of the Post for the associated question.  The user starts on the posts#show page for the question Post, and clicks "Answer".  I'd have thought the code below would pass the id of the question Post to the answer Posts' parent_id.  But it does not.  It returns parent_id = nil

I have a Posts model.  A Post has a post_type_id of 1 (question) or 2 (answer).

All Posts where post_type_id = 2 have a parent_id that points to the id of the question being answered.

On posts#show I have:

```
<% case post_type %> 
  <% when 1 %>
<%= link_to 'Answer', new_post_path(:parent_id => @post.id) %>
  <% else %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on that it takes me to the new_post page and the url is:
    //localhost:3000/posts/new?parent_id=6

(The question in this example has id = 6, so I think that looks correct.)

In my Posts Controller I have:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.parent_id = params[:parent_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :post_type_id, :title, :content, :accepted_answer_id, :parent_id, :score, :answer_count, :favorite_count)
  end
```

My routes are:

```
          posts GET    /posts(.:format)                   posts#index
                POST   /posts(.:format)                   posts#create
       new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)               posts#new
      edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)          posts#edit
           post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#show
                PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#update
                PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#update
                DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#destroy
```

In new.html.erb I have:

```
<h3>New Post</h3>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

And _form.html.erb is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%- f.association :user %>
<%= f.input :post_type_id, collection: post_types, label: 'What do you want to do?' %>
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :content %>
<%- f.input :accepted_answer_id %>
<%- f.input :parent_id %>
<%- f.input :score %>
<%- f.input :answer_count %>
<%- f.input :favorite_count %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how I can get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your routes file.

Comment: It only sets parent_id if `@post.post_type_id == 2`.  is this being set to 2 somewhere else?

Comment: Also post your `show` method in controller.

Comment: Does your form in `new.html.erb` have the `parent_id` anywhere? Even a hidden value?

Comment: the @post.post_type_id is working correctly -- I'm currently doing this in a choice box.  Rails console shows that that part is working.

Comment: can you show us the new.html.erb

Comment: Sure, but without logic in your `create` method to set `parent_id` again from either a form variable, or from your choice logic, then there's no saved state of the `@post` from `new` to `create`. The real problem lies in the contents of your `new.html.erb` and `create` method.

Comment: Is there a field in the form for the parent_id? Because it will create a completely new post object in the create method only using the data passed as parameters (usually form data) in the POST request.

Comment: `link_to 'Answer'....` lies in posts#show as you said in your question, and your `show` method is empty. How are you getting `@post`?

Comment: `create` and the form looks good. I second @ArslanAli's point.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: should I delete <%- f.input :parent_id %> from my form?  (To sjagr's point.)  Do I need to repeat the setting of :parent_id in create?  I just tried those two things and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @post refers to the current post I'm on in posts#show.  So in this post Post.id = 6.  Arslan, maybe I'm not understanding your question.  Please let me know.

Comment: Yes but `def show` should have some sort of `@show = Product.find(params[:post])`

Comment: Please paste your `post_params` method. If that has a `permit`, does the whitelist include `parent_id`?

Comment: Did you mean Post.find(params[:post]) ? (I don't have a Product model)  I tried this & I'm getting an error "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=": def show
    @show = Post.find(params[:post])
  end

Comment: Kristjan, just added it - it does include parent_id

Comment: If you only have 2 post types (either Q or A), I suggest you add a convenient method in your class `def question?{ post_type == 1 }`, so then you don't have to bother with meaningless `case when` and you can write `<%if @post.question? %> ... <% else %>`

Comment: Thanks, I actually have 4 post types, just truncating b/c they're not relevant to this question.

Comment: We don't know what the problem is/ what you're trying to do (anymore ? did you edit the question and removed the description of your problem ?)

Comment: That is what happened, thanks.  I accidentally deleted more than I intended when editing.  I've added a problem summary at the top now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so your user clicks on answer, it then forwards the question ID as a ROOT param (`params[:parent_id]`)

Now, you want to tell your new action that the post you're building is an answer to a question, so this is where you should use the param

*controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.parent_id = params[:parent_id] if params[:parent_id]
```

Then in your form, you can add a hidden field (User don't care about the id). I believe if the field `.parent_id` wasn't set, it will leave a blank value and it's fine

*views/posts/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
```

Then when you POST your new answer, the :parent_id will be sent and you don't need to worry about it

*controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    # No need for the below line, :parent_id is already in post_params
    # @post.parent_id = params[:parent_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(..., :parent_id, ...)
  end
```

EDIT : Answers to your questions in comments

*Why does `@post.parent_id = params[:parent_id]` belongs to #new*

With this line, you actually set the :parent_id memory variable of the "template @post object" you are preparing for the #new action. Now when you render the view, by default every form helper will LOAD the values in memory if they exist. When you're doing `f.input :content`, the form_builder will generate the HTML tags, but also look in the memory for `@post.content`. Because the model was generated blank, there is no value so it will show an empty field. So when you're calling `f.hidden_field :parent_id`, it will actually find the variable (thanks to the code we just added) and use it.

*<%- instead of <%=*

I personally never use `<%-`, and I had to google it, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails). `<%-` will just avoid line breaks, so it would work as well

*Why a hidden field ?*

It's just a matter of user experience. A hidden field will write in the HTML, but will hide it to the user. The user doesn't give a damn shit about your `:parent_id`. You are using ActiveRecord, so IDs look very nice, but if you try other databases system, your ID might look like `0bef0600008de`. And your user definitely doesn't care that he's adding an answer to a question `0bef0600008de`.

However h might be interested in this :

*_form.html.erb*

```
<% if @post.parent_id %> <!-- if variable parent_id exists <=> we are writing an answer -->
  <h2>You are writing an answer for the question <%= Post.find(@post.parent_id).title %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Comment: An alternative syntax to `f.hidden_field` can be `f.input :parent_id, as: :hidden`

Comment: Thanks for posting a potential solution!  Unfortunately I'm still getting parent_id = nil     Are you currently able to get it to work?  I'm wondering where else in my app I could be going wrong....

Comment: Ok, I know that `f.hidden_field` method is annoying, and doesn't work as expected. Try `f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: (params[:parent_id] if params[:parent_id])`.

Comment: Ok, this totally worked!  Yay!  I had tried explicitly stating the controller and didn't undo that before trying your solution, and that had thrown it off, my apologies.  But once I realized my error, it worked great!  Thank you so much!  Why does the setting of :parent_id belong in new & not create?  And is a hidden_field always required, rather than leaving it out with <%- %> like I had done initially?

Comment: Sorry, our comments were simultaneous.  I believe your original solution works.  I'd just made a change that was throwing it off.  Thank you again!

Comment: Edited post to answer your questions