# rails ERB template language construct for <%= vs <% compared with django templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

coming from Django I am wondering how rails people think about <%= %> vs <% %>

From what I see here <%= tag.title %> displays information that's already present like attributes of the obj, like the {{ }} in django, and <% %> always does stuff, like an each loop or if statement, like the {% %} in django.

If that statement fully accurate, or is there a finer line I missed? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you've basically got it down.

```
<% %>
```

Will run ruby code without displaying it

```
<%= %>
```

Will display the information to the screen

```
<%# %>
```

Will comment out ruby code in your view

Here's just a simple example

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) may help you as well.

Comment: thank you. why is there 2 do's there? I've only seen with the one do, `<%  @obj.each do |thing| %>`