# List of articles also displays database info for all articles in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing the Jumpstart tutorial where you have to create a blog in ruby on rails. It is going fine but I have not managed to figure out one thing. 
The root page is supposed to show a list of articles. And it does. Only it also shows this extra bit: 
[Article list and unwanted part at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNGbk.png)

The code I have in the view:

```
<h1> All Articles </h1>


<ul id="articles">
    <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), class: 'article_title' %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "Create New Article", new_article_path, class: 'new_article' %>
```

And here is the relevant code in the controller

```
def index
    @articles = Article.all
end
```

I would appreciate any help on why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Embedded Ruby (ERB), the difference between `<% %>` and `<%= %>` is not simply cosmetic; the latter actually prints the results of the line of code into the html. As such, in your line:

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
```

...You are actually printing the results of running that line of code and displaying it. Or, more specifically, you're displaying loop itself, not just the results of looping through the @articles collection. You'll get a lot of gibberish from haphazardly using the `<%= %>` notation. Just look at when you play around in the console/debugger; running these lines of code makes a lot of noise!

To fix your problem, your loop through @articles should simply look like this:

```
# No "=" here!
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), class: 'article_title' %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

For more information on ERB syntax, look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

For another stack overflow question encompassing this and a few additional notation, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails).

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen it but I actually wasn't even sure how it affected my code even if I had!

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `=` sign of your loop 
So:
 `<% @articles.each do |article| %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <%= content_tag :li, link_to(article.title, article, class: 'article_title') %>
<% end %>
```

Struggled with the same issue for 2 days when starting.