# Each.iterator prints more than it should, Ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

I have this in my html.erb file:

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |result| %>
    <%= simple_format(result.content) %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

The output is the following:

```
nadja kuhn


Zwischen Nadja Dazwischen


[#<PgSearch::Document id: 17, content: "nadja kuhn", searchable_id: 122, searchable_type: "Event", created_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02", updated_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02">, #<PgSearch::Document id: 19, content: "Zwischen Nadja Dazwischen", searchable_id: 124, searchable_type: "Event", created_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02", updated_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02">]
```

The first two lines are printed as expected, but somehow, there comes more, than just the content, namely, the list with the whole entries.

If I write this:

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |result| %>
```

The first two lines disappear, as expected, but somehow, there is still this list:

```
[#<PgSearch::Document id: 17, content: "nadja kuhn", searchable_id: 122, searchable_type: "Event", created_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02", updated_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02">, #<PgSearch::Document id: 19, content: "Zwischen Nadja Dazwischen", searchable_id: 124, searchable_type: "Event", created_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02", updated_at: "2016-03-18 22:45:02">]
```

If I write nothing, then nothing happens. What do I need to do, that this second list doesn't get printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are outputing the line of your iterator:

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |result| %>
```

Notice the extra `=`, which essentially calls `to_s` under the hood. Take it out.

```
<% @pg_search_documents.each do |result| %>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) on the difference between `<% ... %>` and `<%= ... %>`.