# Using Faker directly in an .erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, faker

For a bit of quick-and-dirty hacking, I would like to get some text into a page. This doesn't seem to work...

home.html.erb

```
...
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div><% Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count = 3) %></div>
...
```

I have faker in my Gemfile.

This just produces an empty div. Is there a way of using Faker in this way or do I need to put it into a model?

TIA

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<%= Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count = 3) %>` with the "=" to print out the content

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
...
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div><%= Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count = 3) %></div>
...
```

note the equal sign. note the [difference of ERB tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) in general.