# If condition in rails not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have my code as below

```
<% reported_type = 4 %>
<%=
  if reported_type == 1
    link_to "1 is true", true_path
  else
    link_to "1 is false", false_path
  end

  if reported_type == 2
    link_to "2 is true", true_path
  else
    link_to "2 is false", false_path
  end

  if reported_type == 3
    link_to "3 is true", true_path
  else
    link_to "3 is false", false_path
  end
%>
```

Expected Output: `1 is false2 is false3 is false`

But actual output is `3 is false`

When I comment out the third `if ... else` block, I get `2 is false`.
If it is because of `<%= ... %>`, then no if statement must be rendered, right?

As I am new to Rails, I can't figure out why only the last if statement is rendered. If I mix `<%= ... %>` and `<% .. %>`, my code will not look nice (As I require every block to be executed). Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you do it in rails. It would be enough to wrap each `if` in its individual `<%=` as @potashin suggests, but it still would be very unidiomatic. Here's how it should be done:

```
<% if reported_type == 1 %>
  <%= link_to "1 is true", true_path %>
<% else %>
  <%=  link_to "1 is false", false_path %>
<% end %>
```

Quite cluttered, I know. That's why people like to use other template languages like HAML:

```
- if reported_type == 1
  = link_to "1 is true", true_path
- else
  = link_to "1 is false", false_path
```

To answer your direct question

> I can't figure out why only the last if statement is rendered

That's how ruby works. Return value of a block of code is the last expression evaluated in that block. Which you already observed.

Comment: HAML looks great. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide output `<%=` for each separate `if`, now it just renders the last helper output. Or something like this:

```
<%(1..3).each do |x| %>
  <%= (reported_type == x) ? (link_to "#{x} is true", true_path) : (link_to "#{x} is false", false_path)%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks man. Now I get why only last output is displayed.

Comment: Sincerely, the guy say he's beginning with rails, with a code that is clearly a test. No need to complicate things that much.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the entire expression within `<%= ... %>` evaluates to the value of the last `if-else-block`:

```
if reported_type == 3
  link_to "3 is true", true_path
else
  link_to "3 is false", false_path
end
```

To fix this use separate `<%= ... %>` invocations to wrap each of your if-else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ERB templating language inside your views. Please consult this [resource](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)

As for your code, try the following:

```
<% reported_type = 4 %>

<% if reported_type == 1 %>
    <%= link_to "1 is true", true_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "1 is false", false_path %>
<% end %>

<% if reported_type == 2 %>
   <%= link_to "2 is true", true_path %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "2 is false", false_path %>
<% end %>

...
```

And refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/2162376) answer for correct usage of erb brackets.