# How to get rid of array after .map method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am instantiating a variable like so:

**Searches Controller:**

```
@search_results = Business.near(params[:search_zip], params[:radius]).to_a
```

**Searches View**

```
<%= @search_results.map do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>

=> PetStore FoodStore BeautyStore ClothingStore ["\n", "\n", "\n", "\n"]`
```

How can I get rid of the array at the end?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What `each` are you talking about?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is printed because you are using `<%=` instead of `<%`. Change

```
<%= @search_results.map do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% @search_results.map do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

`map` returns the evaluation of the block. The returned value is then printed because of `<%=`.

Also note you don't need a `map`, `each` is sufficient and will save you resources in this case:

```
<% @search_results.each do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<%=` to `<%`

```
<% @search_results.map do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change from `.map` to `.each` since you aren't trying to change the value of the array. You should be able to fix with this:

```
<% @search_results.each do |sr| %>
  <%= sr.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

The `<%=` means you want to print the value