# Display PDF's uploaded with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I upload files (PDF's only) using paperclip and now want to display these as a PDF in a view.

This gives me an empty frame `<iframe src="<% @document.file %>"></iframe>`
This results in an image `<%= image_tag @document.file(:large) %>`

the files are stored in postgress.

Comment: tried that too - empty iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an syntax "issue":

```
<iframe src="<% @document.file %>"></iframe>
```

Should be

```
<iframe src="<%= @document.file %>"></iframe>
<!-- notice the equals symbol (=) -->
<!-- which prints something into erb file. -->
```

Also, I believe you need to use it's `url`, so I'd be something like this:

```
<iframe src="<%= @document.file.url(:large) %>"></iframe>
```

More info - [What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)

Comment: thanks; aware of difference yet forgot to use it (new to RoR).

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src= <%= @document.url.html_safe %> width="595" height="485" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

https://scalified.com/2018/01/16/injecting-pdf-html-page/

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining what you've done in your example code.