# Rails User user avatar profil picture, in product listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

### i want to use the avatar of the seller in the index and show page of listings

So i put my listing controller:

---

this is the full controller for listing (call service in this example)

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]

  def seller
   @services = Service.where(user: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end


  def index
    if params[:category]
      @services = Service.where(category: params[:category])
    else
      @services =  Service.all
    end
    @seller = Service.find(params[:id]).user
  end

  def show
    @seller = Service.find(params[:id]).user
  end

  def new
    @service = Service.new
  end

  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)
    @service.user_id = current_user.id
    if @service.save
     redirect_to services_path
    else
     render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @service.user  == current_user
      @service.update(service_params)
      redirect_to services_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Este no es su producto"
      render :index
    end
  end

  private
  def service_params
    params.require(:service).permit(:name, :city, :price, :category, :id)
  end

  def check_seller
    @seller = Service.find(params[:user_id]).user
  end

  def find_service
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])
  end

  def check_user
    if current_user != @service.user
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "No puede realizar esta accion"
    end
  end
end
```

and In the show and index page i add this :

```
<% cloudinary_url(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>
```

In my navbar the avatar is working fine with:

```
<%= cl_image_tag current_user.avatar.path, width: 50, height: 50, gravity:    :face, crop: :thumb %>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you please give some more details like html, model ..

Comment: Hello,

This is my listing model

'class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0}
  validates :category, presence:true, inclusion: { in: %w(Check-in Check-out Limpieza), message: "%{value} no es una entrada correcta" }
  #validates :rating, inclusion: {in: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
end'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing "=" in

```
<% cloudinary_url(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>
```

add

```
<%= cloudinary_url(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>
```

it may resolve your issue.

**Edit:**

Please refer this link to understand the syntax difference in erb. [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7996695/2681997)

Comment: Thanks Prakash, on show its working fine, but on the index page i got an error:
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListingsController#index

    Couldn't find Service with 'id'=
   services =  Service.all
   end
   seller = Service.find(params[:id]).user
   end

   def show

Comment: @Tomas, are you sending params[:id] in yours params while accessing params?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: oh sorry can you please add params log for index method call?

Comment: Actually it say:
Request

Parameters:

None

So i think the problem is here

Comment: i've update my question with the full controller listing (call service in the example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127178/discussion-between-prakash-s-and-tomas).

Answer (score 0):

what does

```
<% cloudinary_url(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>
```

return? Does it return a url? If it does, you need to use an image_tag to display it.

```
<%=image_tag cloudinary_url(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>
```

Comment: i change it to 
    <%= cl_image_tag(@seller.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %>

now on the show page its working but i get an error on the Listing index page "Couldn't find Listing with 'id'="

Comment: So my solution is for the show page: <% serv =Service.find(service.id)%> 
<% if serv.user.avatar? %> 
<%= cl_image_tag(Service.find(service.id).user.avatar.path , width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill) %> 
<% else %> 
<h3>no image</h3> 
<% end %>