# Rails App Automatically Renders ActiveRecord Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with the database containing seeded objects. When I access them in a view, all of them get printed onto the bottom of the page. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Here is the code in the view:

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
<h2><%= link_to "#{article.title}", title_path(article.index), {class: "link"} %></h2>
<p><%= article.text[0..article.text.index('.')] + "..." %></p>
```

And here is what is rendered (The blue link and line under is supposed to render, but then all of the seeded articles render):

[image]

Comment: Please show relevant code - for the view and the controller that renders the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in this line

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
```

The '=' character outputs the result of that line. Without the '=' character, the code is evaluated without being printed. Remove the '=' and you should not see the output of the @articles variable.

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) may help.