# Rails 5 form_tag with table and radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, form-helpers

I'm a Rails newbie and trying hard to display the radio button checked for a particular record based on its boolean value in the DB(field-name is 'main'). After displaying all table entries, the user can check another radio button and that must again be updated in DB. So basically any one attachment only can be made main.Whatever I do with form_tag, at most the page displays but with no table at all.

attachments/index.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag user_attachments_path do %>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Select one </th>
        <th> Attachment Name </th>
        <th> Creation Date </th>
        <th> Delete Attachment </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
        <%=hidden_field_tag :main, 'attachment.main' %>
        <tr>
          <td><% radio_button_tag "attachment_id", attachment.id, attachment.main %> </td>
          <td><%= attachment.attach.file.basename %></td>
          <td><%= attachment.posting_date %></td>
          <td><%= button_to "Delete", user_attachment_path(current_user, attachment), method: "delete", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-outline btn-md" %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag "Select Main", :class =>'button' %>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb -

```
post :attachments, to: "attachments#update", as: :attachments
```

Also, do I access the value of newly checked radio like this in my attachments#update because attachment is a local variable and not sure if it has scope outside index.html

```
if params[:attachment][:main] == 'checked'
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Use form for instead of form tag

Comment: Nah, form_for is not used when you have multiple records. form_for is only for one record. Form_tag is the solution but am facing a routing issue.

Comment: Thanks for the table structure in the form_tag, it was helpful !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erb needs to be amended to display. At the moment it is only executing the code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails) might help.

```
<% form_tag user_attachments_path do %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_tag user_attachments_path do %>
```

Comment: yes, I'd already figured that out but the basic issue is with form_tag to direct to a non-RESTful method say update_main in controller similar to this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast. Actually something with form_tag and routes

Comment: The question stated 'Whatever I do with form_tag, at most the page displays but with no table at all' which I answered. You may want to start a new thread for your other question. If you click the submit button, what happens? Look in the logs and you will see what is being passed in the params hash and how it is formatted. Also the radio_button_tag erb is missing the equals sign. tbh, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, so I'm going to post another answer with my assumptions.