# How to output variable in sinatra without <%=

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

In Rails, there exist such helper as "concat" to output variables inside <% %> block for erb remplates. Which helper can I use in Sinatra to perform the same action, without using <%=  %> block ? I mean, something like

```
<%
#code
concat "This should be rendered in HTML, not in console"
#code
%>
```

EDIT
The code in the view is something like this (yep, too much logic, but this is my first app in Ruby):

```
<% Dir.glob('uploaded/*').select do |entry| %>
    <div class="singleFileItem">
    <% if File.directory? entry %>
        <img src="images/folder.png">
    <% else 
       case entry.to_s.split(".")[1]
        when "doc","docx" %>
            <img class="pictogram" src='images/word.png'>
        <% when "xls","xlsx" %>
            <img class="pictogram" src='images/excel.png'>
        <% when "pdf" %>
            <img class="pictogram" src='images/pdf.png'>
        <% when "png", "jpg", "jpeg" %>
            <img class="pictogram" class="imageRaw" src="<%= entry.to_s %>">
        <% else %>
        <% end
       end %>
       <br>
       <span class="subFileText">
        <%= entry.to_s.split("/")[1][0..14] %>...
       </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Rendering of the view depends on gem/file extension you use, this happens the same way in both Sinatra/Rails. If you add a haml gem and use *.haml extension template will be compiled using haml

Comment: @Bohdan, thanks, but that shows, that I should change all layouts to haml. If it is one-paged app, that can be suitable, but if it will be more complex app? Based on your comment, I conclude, that my question just can't be answered because of the idea in erb

Comment: @whodini9, maybe, my question is not clear, I will try to rephrase it:
In erb, inside these `<% %>` how to output value of variable?

Comment: You need to use `<%=` for erb to print the executed code.  What is printed here is analagous to what would print in  irb (Read-Eval-Print) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails

Comment: @whodini9, is it possible to do this in alternative way? Like here: https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

Comment: You can try building your own method and calling it with `<%-`, but I'm not sure this will work. Can you explain why you can't use the `<%=`? Normally you would put your non-print code inside `<%`, then use the `=` explicitly for what you want to print.

Comment: @whodini9, that's true, but I have too much logic in my view. I'm getting the directory files\folders, and making some changes to properly output it up to 18 characters. Something like in the updated question. I wanna to check if name is more than 18 characters and then shrink it and add three dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, guys, I have finally found it. 
I have extended the app.rb file with

```
set :erb, :outvar => '@output_buffer'
def concat(text)
    @output_buffer << text
end
```

And it works. Just type in the .erb view

```
<% concat "Text that should be added to render" %>
```

And you all done. Hope, this will help to someone with similar question