# Index view of Rails model printing string with all model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I just finished Rails' [Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and everything works perfectly except for this mysterious entry that's being printed in the Index view as shown below. I've been trying to find the cause to no avail, neither have I found no suitable terms to Google this issue.
[image]

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Index</h1>
<%= link_to 'New Client', new_client_path %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Issued On</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Finished?</th>
        <th>Payments</th>
    </tr>
    <%= @clients.each do |client| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= client.name %></td>
            <td><%= client.date %></td>
            <td><%= client.note %></td>
            <td><%= client.finished %></td>
            <td><%= client.payment %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_path(client) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client_path(client),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'This client will be permanentally deleted, do you want to continue?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Clients Controller

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @clients = Client.all
    end

    def show
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @client = Client.new
    end

    def edit
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create 
        @client = Client.new(client_params)

        if @client.save
            redirect_to @client
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])

        if @client.update(client_params)
            redirect_to @client
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @client = Client.find(params[id])
        @client.destroy

        redirect_to clients_path
    end

    private

        def client_params
            params.require(:client).permit(:name, :date, :note, :finished, :payment)
        end
end
```

Comment: `<%= @clients.each do |client| %>` remove `=` read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/1297435

Comment: Thanks I didn't know when to and not to use =

Answer (score 2):

Remove `=` from `<%= @clients.each do |client| %>`. It is outputting result of `each` which you don't need to print.

In ERB,

- `<%= %>`

  executes ruby code as well as outputs the result

  *For example:* `<%= client.name %>`
- `<% %>`

  executes ruby code but doesn't output the result

  *For example:* `<% @clients.each do |client| %>....<% end %>`