# Rails how to make conditional inside iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to use a conditional inside a iteration but did not worked so, here the scenario:

in this case if the if the order or the product is present should just show the order and products with the feedback.

but even if is present show the feedback with odata and pdata.

someone know why?

```
<% @feedbacks.each do |feedback| %>
      <% if order.present?  && product.present?  %>
      <% order = feedback.order %>
      <% product = order.product %>
      <% else %>
<% odata = feedback.odata %>
  <% pdata = odata.pdata %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You are missing a `end`. The `each` execute the block between `do` and `end`.

Comment: thank you Alejandro is not missing is that have more code down so, i just pust that part

Comment: Ok, please take a look at @Md. Farhan Memon's asnwer, please pay attention to the indentation of this answer, and edit your Post with all the code with this identation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to do,

```
<% @feedbacks.each do |feedback| %>
  <% if (order = feedback.order).present? && (product = feedback.product).present? %>
    <%= order.title %>
    <%= product.title %>
  <% else %>
    <%= (odata = feedback.odata).name %>
    <%= odata.pdata.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note: `title` and `name` are assumed columns, replace it with your required/respected attribute.
Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/6548745) to understand the difference between various erb tags.

Comparison:

- for the `if` condition you are trying to call `order` and `product` directly, which will throw error as they are related to `feedback`.
- `<% %>` just executes the ruby code, you wanted to print the data so need to use `<%= %>`.
- no need to save them in variable when you are not going to use it. I have saved them while checking the existence of the object in the condition and could use to display without querying the db.

Comment: yes, but this statement is not the same that i did?

Comment: now shows undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class

Comment: @bookaka check the updated answer, and if still there's error, which line?

Comment: @md-farhan-memon ok. a moment

Comment: so, what's the difference of your method with mine? seems like the same

Comment: yes thank you @md-farhan-memon. very well explained. just one thing

besides that worked but now shows #<Order:0x007f36bbab93b8> #<Product:0x007f36bba56808>

above the feedbacks, maybe this is related with the ()?

Comment: Nope, it is not because of that, replace `order`, `product`, `odata` n `pdata` with the respected attributes you wanna display. `product.title` for example. Wait, i'll update that in answer.