# Get ERB tag value within html qith JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

So I have this piece of html

```
<td class="role-span"><span class="label"><% user.role %></span></td>
```

And I'm trying to get user.role value for each cell of the table like so

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.role-span').map(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        })
    });
```

I'm able to get the span text value if I it is hard coded but if it's a `<% %>` it doesn't work anymore.

Any thoughts on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% %>` will only execute ruby code but print result

Use `<%= %>` to print result.

Detail is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/2549588

And the `role-span` is on a `td` so if you want to get all span's text you should do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.role-span').map(function() {
        alert($(this).find('span.label').text());
    });
});
```

Or maybe you should use `each` instead of `map`, because you just want to do a loop not get an array.

Comment: Thanks I did not see that. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @donald above you need to replace

```
<td class="role-span"><span class="label"><% user.role %></span></td>
```

with

```
<td class="role-span"><span class="label"><%= user.role %></span></td>
```

As

- `<% %>` just evaluates the expression inside it whereas
- `<%= %>` evaluates and print the result returned by the expression.