# Each loop outputs an unwanted dump of the records after the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just following some rails tutorials, and built a basic CRUD app (a blog with comment system).
My problem is that when I loop through each comment for a post, an annoying dump of the records is displayed after the each loop.
It looks like there is some inspect dump, but I can't find the reason for this.
Here is the code for the loop:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<%= @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<div class="well">
  <p><strong><%= comment.username %></strong>: <%= comment.body %></p>
</div>
<%= link_to "[X]", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
<hr>
<% end %>
```

Here is also the comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:username, :body)
  end
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end


end
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Ruby on rails each problem]

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're using `<%= %>`, which is the ERB tag that evaluates its content as Ruby and then prints it to the page. But you don't want to print out the value of `@post.comments.each do |comment|`; you just want to evaluate it. That's what the `<% %>` tag (no `=`) is for.

The reason you're seeing the text you are is that `<%= %>` implicitly calls `to_s` on its content.

This answer has a full list of ERB tag types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/882025

Answer (score 2):

It's the `Enumerable` returned by the `each` method. Change

```
<%= @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

to

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

just because you don't want to see that

Comment: oh, that was so easy, thanks! What is the purpose of this exactly, Can this be used as a replacement for inspect?

Comment: It's returned because enumerable's methods are chainable