# How to conditionally display a div inside a html erb file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a Button based on wether the id exists.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= @customer.id? %>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <%= button_to 'Kundenrofil', customer_path(@customer), method: :get %>
   </div>
<%= end %>
```

I use this inside a form for making a new customer and also for editing a customer.

If I edit a customer everything works fine but if I make a new user it gives me an error because

`id=nil`

How do I do it in the **_form.html.erb**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% unless @customer.id.nil? %>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <%= button_to 'Kundenrofil', customer_path(@customer), method: :get %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

You have to put `if/unless` with expression. So change `@customer.id?` with `unless @customer.id.nil?`. Also notice `<%` instead of `<%=`.
`<%=` is used when we want to render something on the page.
`<%` is used to Execute the ruby code within the brackets.
Change `<%= end %>` to `<% end %>`

Ref [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/297087) to know about the differences.

Comment: Glad it works for you, do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: How about just `if @customer.id`?