# Console Data for my categories is showing in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a novice to rails but I created a group of categories with the intention of using them as a filter for items in my application. However in listing them it seems like data that should be console only is showing up in my view. How do I get rid of this?
[What shows in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo1e1.png)

The code in my view are as follows:

```
<%= State.all.each do |state| %>
<%= link_to state.status, tickets_path(state: state.status) %>
<div class="badge">
<%= state.tickets.count %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Where State is my "category" and Status is the "category name" and Ticket is the form submission or "item" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= State.all.each do |state| %>` delete the '=' and its done.

Comment: It helps to provide an explanation for _why_ that works. The reason it works is because in ERB `<%= %>` means "render the return value of the Ruby code following the `=` sign," while `<% %>` means "execute the Ruby code following the `=` sign but do not render its return value." [More info elsewhere on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7996695/3784008)