# Rails 5 each loop activestorage files displays files attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I updated Rails to 5.2 version with ActiveStorage

Everything works fine, but when I perform a loop through my model attached files in order to display them as bootstrap cards, I see my files attributes on the page. 
I don't want it to display anything.

How can I prevent that?

```
  <strong style="margin: 10px">Files :</strong>
  <div class="card-columns">
  <%= @mymodel.files.each do |file| %>

  <% end %>
  </div>
```

[what it makes on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVC35.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `=` from your loop header...

Instead of

```
<%= @mymodel.files.each do |file| %>
```

Use

```
<% @mymodel.files.each do |file| %>
```

Checkout [what the difference is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)