# Remove array from showing under my rails erb-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a checkbox form where you can select many customers to attend a single event. The form works but there is an array of all customers under it and I can't figure out how to remove it.

events.rb

```
def addcustomer
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @customer = Customer.all
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
    get  'addcustomer', on: :member, as: 'add'
  end
```

addcustomerform.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "event[customer_ids][]", nil%>
  <%= @customer.each do |customer| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "event[customer_ids][]", customer.id,
     @event.customer_ids.include?(customer.id), id:dom_id(customer) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(customer), customer.id %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(customer), customer.name %> --
    <%= label_tag dom_id(customer), customer.email %> --
    <%= label_tag dom_id(customer), customer.phone %>
    <br>
  <% end %>  
  <br>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Here is a photo of what the issue looks like: [image]

Here is the repo
https://github.com/robbiesoho/fanfactory

I hope someone can help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not the params that are shown there but all the customers.
If you replace `<%= @customer.each do |customer| %>` with `<% @customer.each do |customer| %>`

The difference is that I remove the `=`. The `=` means that the line should be added to the HTML as text. on that line is the `@customer` array, and the result f `@customer.to_s` is what you see there.

For more information, please read: [What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/5600652)

Comment: So simple, yet I would have never thought of that on my own. Thanks a million