# Can't print data "name" ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to print data from a object "root" to a table, everythink work fine but not printing this name i dont know why.

Code :

```
<% root = NameOfDatabase.find_by_d_id(d.id) %>
            <%  logger.info root.inspect %>
            <% if root.nil? %>
           <td class="col-4"> <% "-" %> </td>
           <%  else %>
           <td class="col-4"> <% root.name %> </td>
           <% end %>
```

Picture: [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYn3S.png)

Log file :

```
...  
#<Name**** id: ****, d_id: ****, name: "Alice", dd_id: ****>
Completed in 99ms (View: 7, DB: 33) | 200 OK [https://*********/dd/search_ajax?option=active&query=s001]
```

As following in root we have data i want only print root.name in table !!

thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`

1. `<% %>` will just evaluate the expression, it won't output the result to ERB template
2. `<%= %>` will evaluate the expression and outputs to ERB template.

Try the below:

```
<% root = NameOfDatabase.find_by_student_id(student.id) %>
<%  logger.info root.inspect %>
<% if root.nil? %>
<td class="col-4"> <%= "-" %> </td>
<%  else %>
<td class="col-4"> <%= root.name %> </td>
<% end %>
```

Reference:

[What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7996695/11350468)