# Rails showing ActiveRecord_Relation in my view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Well my problem is when i call my model Question and show in a .each do, my view show the ActiveRecord but i don't now how to hide this or the right way to show my questions without the ActiveRecord.

In my view the content show like this:

[image]

```
<%= @questions = Question.all.order(:id).reverse_order %>

<% @questions.each do |question|  %>
  <% if @course.id == 1 %>

      <h5><%= link_to question.title, question ,  class: 'reply text-light text-decoration-none' %></h5>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)

You could use `<% %>` instead of `<%= %>`:

```rb
<% @questions = Question.all.order(id: :desc) %>
```

And it's better to put that to controller:

```rb
class QuestionsController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all.order(id: :desc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if i want to call a Model in view, just create a input type="hidden" like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= @questions = Question.all.order(:id).reverse_order %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use url_helpers provided by Rails. See Examples provided under [link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) docs.

Also I would suggest to follow the recommendation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66470651/936494 and in your view change following

```
<h5><%= link_to question.title, question ,  class: 'reply text-light text-decoration-none' %></h5>
```

to

```
<h5><%= link_to question.title, question_path(question),  class: 'reply text-light text-decoration-none' %></h5>
```

And if you don't have url_helpers available, then the 2nd argument should be a URL to a resource in your application.

Hope that helps. Thanks.