# What is the meaning of the <%= %> HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, tags

I have been working on a Webpack project. For anyone unfamiliar with Webpack, it is a bundler that takes all your files and spits out a final product.

I wanted to inject one HTML file into another, like an import or require(). I have been using this GitHub template to help me piece together my project. https://github.com/dharmikumbhani/webpack-multipage-starter

In webpack-multipage-starter/src/page-index/index.html on line 10 and 11 there is the following:

```
<!-- intercepted by a resourceQuery in the webpack config -->
<%= require('../partials/nav.html?raw') %>
```

This line gets intercepted by a resourceQuery (in the webpack.common.js configuration) and the HTML file is injected into this position.

What is the meaning of this HTML tag?

> <%= =>

All I know is that it holds a Java-Script expression which gets evaluated during the Webpack build process.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)

Comment: @RobMoll — Webpack isn't Ruby though

Comment: Hi, @RobMoll I had a look into this. Is ruby related to HTML, JS, or Webpack? If so where and how?

Comment: @voxelfox — Ruby is a programming language. JS is a programming language. Webpack is written in JS not Ruby.

Comment: @Quentin Precisely what I thought. The closest that I can get is JSP expression tags. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jsp-expression-tag/) but that's Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an [EJS template](https://ejs.co/). It is used by [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to generate html pages typically for bootstrapping your Multipage apps or SPA apps.